# VBA Excel - How to delete duplicate combinations

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a code to write all the possible combinations with 3 numbers using a list of numbers.

```
Dim min, max, mppt1, mppt2, mppt3, reference As Integer

'seting the range of numbers
min = Range("AA3").Value
max = Range("AB3").Value

For mppt1 = min To max

    For mppt2 = min To max

        For mppt3 = min To max

        Range("AA" & reference).Value = mppt1
        Range("AB" & reference).Value = mppt2
        Range("AC" & reference).Value = mppt3

        referencia = reference + 1

        Next mppt3

    Next mppt2

Next mppt1
```

This works fine. But then, i need to delete all duplicate combinations (independent of the order)

For example, if i have this combinations:

```
16 | 17 | 18
16 | 18 | 17
18 | 17 | 17
18 | 16 | 16
```

After the delete, i should have this output:

```
16 | 17 | 18
18 | 17 | 17
18 | 16 | 16
```

How can i put this logic in my code?

Comment: sort horizontally then remove duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than getting rid of the duplicates, why not avoid avoid outputting them to start off with?

Instead of your second and third loops starting from `min`, have them start from the previous loop variable. Here's a similar working example I mocked up:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim min As Integer, max As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    min = 16
    max = 18

    For i = min To max
        For j = i To max
            For k = j To max
                    Debug.Print i, j, k
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

this prints the following into the immediate window:

```
 16       16     16 
 16       16     17 
 16       16     18 
 16       17     17 
 16       17     18 
 16       18     18 
 17       17     17 
 17       17     18 
 17       18     18 
 18       18     18
```

Comment: @Guilherme If this is the answer, mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.  I added some code to add up the 3 cells and put the answer in column 5.  Then I sort by column 5.  The next loop uses the totals and deletes any total that is a duplicate each time the total changes.......

```
Dim min, max, mppt1, mppt2, mppt3, reference As Integer

'seting the range of numbers
min = Range("f1").Value
max = Range("g1").Value
reference = 1
For mppt1 = min To max

    For mppt2 = min To max

        For mppt3 = min To max

        Range("A" & reference).Value = mppt1
        Range("B" & reference).Value = mppt2
        Range("C" & reference).Value = mppt3

        reference = reference + 1

        Next mppt3

    Next mppt2

Next mppt1

Dim r As Integer

Range("A1:E1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("a1:a27") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:E27")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Dim Col1 As Integer
Dim Col2 As Integer
Dim Col3 As Integer

Col1 = Cells(1, 1)
Col2 = Cells(1, 2)
Col3 = Cells(1, 3)

r = 2

Do Until Len(Trim(Cells(r, 1))) = 0

    DoEvents
    startrow = r

    Col1 = Cells(r, 1)
    Col2 = Cells(r, 2)
    Col3 = Cells(r, 3)

    r = r + 1

    Do While Cells(r, 1) = Col1

        DoEvents

        If Cells(r, 2) = Col2 And Cells(r, 3) = Col3 Then
            Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            If Cells(r, 2) = Col3 And Cells(r, 3) = Col2 Then
                Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                r = r + 1
            End If
        End If

    Loop

    r = startrow + 1
Loop
```

Cells(1, 5).EntireColumn.ClearContents

Comment: Summing and deleting on the sum will produce false positives:  {16,17,18} is the same sum as {17,17,17}

Comment: @ScottCraner........you are correct.  this won't work like I thought it would..........back to the drawing board

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Meanwhile, I'm trying to do something with sort horizontally like Scott said. But i'm not there yet.

Comment: @Guilherme.............I've modified the code in my answer.  I think it will give you the unique combinations you are looking for......

Comment: @Shaves Thank you very much. Indeed was a better solution then mine. But the solution made by CallumDA was the one that gave me the better output.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to collect the unique sums as keys and the individual values as an array item then write the arrays back to the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub saqwjh()
    Dim d As Long, k As Variant, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For d = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If Not dict.Exists(Application.Sum(.Rows(d))) Then
                dict.Add Key:=Application.Sum(.Rows(d)), _
                         Item:=Array(.Cells(d, "A").Value2, _
                                     .Cells(d, "B").Value2, _
                                     .Cells(d, "C").Value2)
            End If
        Next d
        For Each k In dict.Keys
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Resize(1, 3).Offset(1, 0) = dict.Item(k)
        Next k
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]